# Google Appengine routing fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I failed webapp2 routing.

My model :

```
class Letter(ndb.Model):
    letter = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

my handler:

```
lass GoLetter(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, letter_letter):
       pass

       template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('detail.html')
       self.response.write(template.render())



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
   webapp2.Route('/', MainPage),
   webapp2.Route('/letter/([-\w]+)', handler=GoLetter),
], debug=True)
```

and my template :

```
 {% for letter in letters %}
     <a href="/letter/?letter_letter={{ letter.letter }}">{{ letter.letter }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

I get only 404 Not Found.
Please can you say me where am I wrong ? thanks.

Comment: Sorry you've been working on this for many hours, but you've got to define the problem better. Which 'routing' failed? What are you trying to do? Why did you add a pass under the get handler? What's a sample of letter? What URL fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the link in you template has a different form than the route defined for the application.

You defined that your endpoint is `/letter/([-\w]+)`, but your link goes to `/letter/?letter_letter=a`.

Replace the link with

```
<a href="/letter/{{ letter.letter }}">{{ letter.letter }}</a>
```

**EDIT:**
For some reason having webapp2.Route makes things to not work. Replace `webapp2.Route('/letter/([-\w]+)', handler=GoLetter)` with `('/letter/([-\w]+)', GoLetter)`.

Comment: it didnt work, please can you help me, I have been working to solve for hours  :(

Comment: For some reason, having webapp2.Route makes things to not work. Replace webapp2.Route('/letter/([-\w]+)', handler=GoLetter), with ('/letter/([-\w]+)', GoLetter).  I tested this on the playground https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/p/6727161104826368/#helloworld.py

Comment: yea, it worked. thank you so much Sebastian, I appreciate your help :)